# Propositional truncation and information hiding

Tags: type-theory, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, homotopy-type-theory

I have a question regarding propositional truncation $||$-$||$ in homotopy type theory. According to the introduction rule of $||$-$||$, if $a:A$, then $|a|:||A||$. My question is, if $||A||$ is inhabited, what about $A$? Does it imply that $A$ is inhabited (though the inhabitant is unknown/underspecified)?

If we think $|$-$|:A\rightarrow||A||$ as a way to hide information (i.e., proof objects of $A$), then that means that such information must exist, right? Though it's in an anonymous/underspecified way...

I am not sure if my understanding is correct. Let me know if I get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your understanding is correct.

The only way to build an inhabitant of $\|A\|$ is to use an inhabitant of $A$.
So you can say that "intuitively" if $\|A\|$ is inhabited then $A$ is inhabited, but that does not mean that you have a map $f:\|A\|\rightarrow A$.

Propositional truncation hides information, but sometimes in a surprising way, as shown by N. Kraus [here](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2013/10/28/the-truncation-map-_-%E2%84%95-%E2%80%96%E2%84%95%E2%80%96-is-nearly-invertible/), and further discussed [here](https://homotopytypetheory.org/2014/02/24/composition-is-not-what-you-think-it-is-why-nearly-invertible-isnt/).

Comment: Thanks! Then my question is, what is the difference between $A\ true$ in MLTT and $|a|:|A|$ in HoTT? Because it seems that both serve to hide the information carried by the proof objects of $A$.